# How to set thread affinity on Windows to the maximum using std::reduce

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl

I have a code for unifying polyhedrons that looks like this:

```
std::vector<Geometry> toMerge;

// filling "toMerge" with data here.

Geometry g = std::reduce(std::execution::par,
    toMerge.begin(), toMerge.end(),
    toMerge.front(), [](Geometry& g1, Geometry& g2) {
    return mergeGeometries(g1, g2); // heavy process
});
```

It works, but it seems to be heavily underusing my CPU:

[image]

You can notice it does use all the cores when a spike occurs simultaneously on all of them, but later on, it all falls into the 4 cores on the top.

It could be that, after the spikes, there were no more tasks for more than 4 cores to work on, but that is not the case, since we are talking about a couple hundreds of geometries to be merged together.

Comment: The OS is good about scheduling threads without maxing out the system. And chances are that `std::reduce()` is not trying to create a new thread for every item in the `vector` up front. So there is likely not enough work to keep all 16 cores maxed out 100% of the time, especially as earlier items finish their work and Cores become freed up to take on new work.

Comment: If you really want to control the thread affinity, you will have to loop through the `vector` items manually, creating your own threads as needed, and then you can use `SetThreadAffinityMask()` or `SetThreadIdealProcessor()` on each thread to suit your needs.

Comment: Not sure if it applies to your version of Windows, but you should watch out for power saving schemes, and set it to "performance" to make sure all cores are being used. Synchronization (critical sections in the algorithm when merging data), memory latency, and disk latency (only in case of huge input data) can also make the CPU cores underutilized.